# How can I sum value from array in dictionary with python?

Tags: python, dictionary

the dictionary data look like this

```
[
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 30},
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 40},
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 20},
{'br' : 'Dede', 'mnt' : '2020-5', 'vl' : 20},
{'br' : 'Dede', 'mnt' : '2020-5', 'vl' : 40},]
```

and the result is sum vl if only br and mnt have same value

```
[
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 90},
{'br' : 'Dede', 'mnt' : '2020-5', 'vl' : 60}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `pandas`, try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 30},
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 40},
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 20},
{'br' : 'Dede', 'mnt' : '2020-5', 'vl' : 20},
{'br' : 'Dede', 'mnt' : '2020-5', 'vl' : 40}]

# turn data into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# take the sum when br and mnt are the same
df_grouped = df.groupby(['br','mnt']).agg({'vl':'sum'}).reset_index()
df_grouped
```

This outputs:

```
    br      mnt     vl
0   Dede    2020-5  60
1   Kadek   2020-10 90
```

If you really need to, you can turn it back into a list of dictionaries with:

```
df_grouped.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Kris, I also resolve it by Counter


`from collections import Counter`

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter 

data = [
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 30},
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 40},
{'br' : 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'vl' : 20},
{'br' : 'Dede', 'mnt' : '2020-5', 'vl' : 20},
{'br' : 'Dede', 'mnt' : '2020-5', 'vl' : 40},]

cnt = Counter()

for i in data:
    cnt[i['br'], i['mnt']] += i['value']

result = ([{'br': k[0], 'mnt': k[1], 'value': v}
        for k, v in cnt.items()])

print(result)
```

output:

```
[{'br': 'Kadek', 'mnt' : '2020-10', 'value': 90},
{'br': 'Dede', 'mnt' : '2020-5', 'value': 60}]
```